# Insert XML from one file into another with xmlstarlet?

Tags: xml, insert, xmlstarlet

Is there a way to insert XML from one file into another using xmlstarlet or am I stuck stringing together a bunch of -s commands? I have a fairly large chunk to insert. Would I be better off writing some xsl with that chunk in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would I be better off writing some xsl with that chunk in it?

I think you would be better off using XSL; the [document()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-document) function lets you get XML from another file. xmlstarlet's ed subcommand doesn't have access to [document()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-document) and it lacks a way of accessing other files.