# How to copy XML subtree from several file into one using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, copy, append, xslt-1.0

### Multiple files

I got a series of documents (`generated-*.svg`) following this structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
  <defs>
    <font id="Hanzi-Pinyin-ruby-font" horiz-adv-x="254">
      <font-face font-family="Droid Sans Fallback" units-per-em="256" panose-1="2 11 5 2 0 0 0 0 0 1" ascent="267" descent="-68" alphabetic="0"/>
      <missing-glyph horiz-adv-x="256" d="M75 183H181V0H75V183ZM88 13H167V170H88V13Z"/>
      <glyph unicode="&#xF900;" glyph-name="豈" horiz-adv-x="256" d=""/>
    </font>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

### Task

For each `generated-*.svg`:

1. I would like to get the resulting sequence for `/svg/defs/font/glyph` ;
2. **Append** the sequence, to an existing file, **in the same location/xpath** and keep existing nodes.

So moving from generated file to a common file.

### Question

How can I copy the resulting sequence of `/svg/defs/font/glyph`, from each `generated-*.svg`, and insert it into a target file in the same xpath? Resulting output is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%">
  <defs>
    <font id="Hanzi-Pinyin-ruby-font" horiz-adv-x="254">
      <font-face font-family="Droid Sans Fallback" units-per-em="256" panose-1="2 11 5 2 0 0 0 0 0 1" ascent="267" descent="-68" alphabetic="0"/>
      <missing-glyph horiz-adv-x="256" d="M75 183H181V0H75V183ZM88 13H167V170H88V13Z"/>
      <glyph unicode="&#xF900;" glyph-name="豈" horiz-adv-x="256" d=""/>
      <glyph unicode="&#xF901;" glyph-name="更" horiz-adv-x="256" d=""/><!-- from: generated-01.svg -->
      <glyph unicode="&#xF902;" glyph-name="車" horiz-adv-x="256" d=""/><!-- from: generated-01.svg -->
      <glyph unicode="&#xF903;" glyph-name="賈" horiz-adv-x="256" d=""/><!-- from: generated-02.svg -->
      <glyph unicode="&#xF904;" glyph-name="滑" horiz-adv-x="256" d=""/><!-- from: generated-02.svg -->
      <glyph unicode="&#xF905;" glyph-name="串" horiz-adv-x="256" d=""/><!-- from: generated-02.svg -->
      <glyph unicode="&#xF906;" glyph-name="句" horiz-adv-x="256" d=""/><!-- from: generated-03.svg -->
      <glyph unicode="&#xF907;" glyph-name="龜" horiz-adv-x="256" d=""/><!-- from: generated-03.svg -->
      <glyph unicode="&#xF908;" glyph-name="龜" horiz-adv-x="256" d=""/><!-- from: generated-03.svg -->
    </font>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

### Related questions

- [How to copy/move an XML subtree from one file to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746837/how-to-copy-move-an-xml-subtree-from-one-file-to-another)
- [Insert XML from one file into another with xmlstarlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696424/insert-xml-from-one-file-into-another-with-xmlstarlet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file `collection.xml` with the contents

```
<files>
  <file>generated-01.svg</file>
  <file>generated-02.svg</file>
  <file>generated-03.svg</file>
  ...
</files>
```

then use one XSLT stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<xsl:param name="col-url" select="'collection.xml'"/>
<xsl:variable name="col-doc" select="document($col-url)"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/svg:svg/svg:defs/svg:font">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document($col-doc/files/file)/svg:svg/svg:defs/svg:font/svg:glyph"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You might need to add an `xsl:output` directive to add the DOCTYPE node in the output and to get indentation.